# Is there a way to vectorize a 2D numpy array that uses start/end slicing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 2D numpy array. In a foor loop, a filter window is estimated around each specified value (missing values). In my example the window size is 5x5. Then, median values of neighborhoods are calculated for each missing value. I can solve the problem with a for-loop,  as below:

```
        for i in range(len(miss_x)):
            cur_x = miss_x[i]
            cur_y = miss_y[i]

            a_x = np.fmax(0, cur_x - 2)
            b_x = np.fmin(depth_img.shape[0], cur_x + 2)
            a_y = np.fmax(0, cur_y - 2)
            b_y = np.fmin(depth_img.shape[1], cur_y + 2)

            window = filtered[a_x: b_x + 1, a_y: b_y + 1]

            mask_zero_depth = (window != np.asarray(0))
            non_z_window = np.ma.masked_array(window, mask_zero_depth)
            non_z_window = window[np.where(non_z_window > 0)]

            if not (np.all(non_z_window == 0)):
                avg_val = np.median(non_z_window.ravel())
                diff_sum = diff_sum + np.abs(filtered[cur_x, cur_y] - avg_val) / avg_val
                filtered[cur_x, cur_y] = avg_val
```

Of course, as expected, this is not an efficient solution. My question is how can I achieve this without a loop in a vectorized way. I tried below code, but that gave "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" error. Here is what I tried:

```
    i = np.meshgrid(np.arange(len(miss_x)), sparse=True)
    cur_x = miss_x[i]
    cur_y = miss_y[i]

    a_x = np.fmax(0, cur_x - 2)
    b_x = np.fmin(depth_img.shape[0], cur_x + 2)
    a_y = np.fmax(0, cur_y - 2)
    b_y = np.fmin(depth_img.shape[1], cur_y + 2)

    window = filtered[a_x: b_x + 1, a_y: b_y + 1]
```

I also tried with slice objects but that did not work as well. So, how can I accomplish this in a vectorized way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering about the solution, well I couldn't find a direct solution about vectorized slicing, instead I solved my problem with an indirect way and an assumption of fixed 5x5 filter windows as below:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib as npm

window = npm.repmat([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2], missings.shape[1], 1)
missing_rows = npm.repmat(missings[0], 25, 1)
missing_cols = npm.repmat(missings[1], 25, 1)

row_bounds = missings[0, :, np.newaxis] + window
#check for the boundary
row_bounds = np.where(row_bounds >= depth_img.shape[0], -1, row_bounds)  
col_bounds = missings[1, :, np.newaxis] + window
col_bounds = np.where(col_bounds >= depth_img.shape[1], -1, col_bounds)

missing_bounds = np.array(list(product(row_bounds.transpose(), col_bounds.transpose())))
missing_bounds = np.transpose(missing_bounds, (1, 0, 2))

if np.count_nonzero(missing_bounds < 0) > 0:
    cond_rows = (missing_bounds[0] < 0)
    cond_cols = (missing_bounds[1] < 0)
    (missing_bounds[0])[cond_rows] = missing_rows[cond_rows]
    (missing_bounds[1])[cond_rows] = missing_cols[cond_rows]
    (missing_bounds[0])[cond_cols] = missing_rows[cond_cols]
    (missing_bounds[1])[cond_cols] = missing_cols[cond_cols]

missing_wins = filtered[missing_bounds[0], missing_bounds[1]]

# to be able to skip zeros inside win, 
# we use nanmedian and for that first initialize zeros with nan
missing_wins[missing_wins == 0] = np.nan
median_of_nonzeros = np.nanmedian(missing_wins, axis=0)

# if all values are nan then make it zero for the next iteration
median_of_nonzeros[np.isnan(median_of_nonzeros)] = 0
filtered[missings[0], missings[1]] = median_of_nonzeros
```

So basically, I create all the filtered neighborhoods before processing, with an assumption of 5x5 (at borders indices are going to be negatives and I assume for these negatives that the values are the same with the missing points.) Then I take median filters of these neighborhoods except that of zero values (which is assigned/assumed as nan values).

Regarding the slicing problem, I guess there is no direct way to solve that, as you need to give a vector argument to the numpy arange() or linspace() which is not possible (e.g. np.arange(a_vector) or np.linspace(vector_of_starts, vector_of_ends, vector_of_sizes))